# What does /*!*/ mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and am reading code with `/*!*/` in what seem like strange places.  For instance class methods defined as:

```
protected override OptionsParser/*!*/ CreateOptionsParser()
protected override void ParseHostOptions(string/*!*/[]/*!*/ args)
```

Unfortunately `/*!*/` is not googleable.  What does it mean?

Comment: ok, this is fun; Why should anybody put such a comment there ?

Comment: Where did you see this code?  Is it part of a tutorial or a project?  Maybe auto-generated code?

Comment: You might want to look for the cause in the editors your predecessors used. Sometimes comments at odd places are used to circumvent parsing-problems of highlighting editors. (Used to be the case with LPC and its #' - lambda syntax)

Comment: Just to be clear, as far as the language is concerned, it means *nothing*. It is just a comment containing an exclamation mark. But the question of what the programmer who put it there meant by it, is a good one.

Comment: I am looking at the IronPython console code, which has many of these type of comments.

Comment: @DownVoter - the down voter why do you not state why the comment was downvoted?  Again StackOverflow developers why can you not add who downvoted the responses or force a reason why it was downvoted?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's likely an attempt to get Spec# style annotations into a non-Spec# build.  The ! annotation in Spec# means the value is not-null.  The author is likely trying to indicate that both the return values, args array and all of the elements in args are always non-null values.

Spec# Link:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

Quick Spec# Overview:

Spec# is a .Net language created via a Microsoft Research Project.  It is an extension of the C# language which attempts to embed code contracts into the type system.  The most prominent are non-nullable types (indicated with ! after the type name), checked exceptions and pre/post conditions.

Comment: Another way to do this is place `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<OptionsParser>() != null);` in the method, which would ideally show up in the accompanying documentation.

Comment: @JaredPar: could fill in some more details? What is a #Spec-build? From the answers so far, this is the only one which seems to have a clue on what is going on.

Comment: @jsbueno, added a quick overview of Spec#.  The best explanation though is at the link I added.  Very detailed documentation can be found there.

Comment: @JaredPar I didn't downvote you but I really hate how SO does not implement a way even in the activity section to see who downvoted, or force a reason why there was a down vote.  Happens to me all the time and of course the downvoter does not explain..

Comment: Spec# is a superset of C# which has constructs for formal specification and allows formal static verificatione (along with additional runtime checks). You can comment out Spec#-specific language constructs (such as `!`-Types) and get valid C# which seems to have happened in your case. For further information I suggest following Jared's Link.

Comment: @JonH: See this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post. Upvote early, upvote often :-).

Answer (score 19):

It's a comment that contains an '!'

Anything enclosed in an /* */ is a comment which will be ignored when the code compiles.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about C# specifically, as it might be a special notation for something, but i use a similar technique in any language that supports open/close, multi-line comment tokens to allow me to quickly comment and uncomment multiple lines with a single character change, like so:

```
/*!*/
this is live code (and will probably cause a compilation error)
/*!*/

/*!* /
this is commented code (and should never cause a compilation error)
/*!*/
```

The reason for the `!` is because constructs like `/**` are common tokens used by documentation tools.

There are other techniques as well when the language supports single-line comment tokens, `//` (and implements them like C++ and Java):

```
///* - opening comments can be commented-out so what follows isn't a comment.
this is live code
//*/ - closing comment are not commented-out by single-line comments.
```

So you can then remove the first single-line comment token, `//`, to produce a kind of "toggle":

```
/* this is now commented.
this is also commented.
//*/ this line is live code.
```

Comment: +1: doesn't answer the question, but is a really nasty^Wgreat hack :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a comment with '!'. Probably the programmer wanted to make sure you noticed the first method returned a OptionsParser, and the second one received an array of strings, and not only a string.

You can remove them, and they'll continue to work fine =)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a [delimited comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(VS.71).aspx); probably your programmer just marked that points to discuss later.

Comment: I've heard of people who make a habit of downvoting every other answer when they submit one - maybe that's what happened here.

Comment: This is one of the bad things about stackoverflow- a guy/gal with a mental disorder can do very crazy things here.

Comment: On the other hand, people might have objected to "multiline comment" for a one-character comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* is start comment
*/ is end comment

everything between is the comment
you can even tell that SO highlights that area as a comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, it is a comment. Additionally, it seems to me that the '!' is used for demarcation. It seems to aid in identifying points of interest and serves like eye-candy.

Comment: Those brackets sure are interesting!