# What does /*!*/ signal in C# source code (as seen in the IronPython project)

Tags: comments, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does /*!*/ mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178747/what-does-mean-in-c)

I have been poking around in the IronPython 2.6 source code and noticed that the comment /*!*/ appears often. Example in ArrayGlobalAllocator.cs:

```
public ArrayGlobalAllocator(PythonContext/*!*/ context) {
```

It doesn't seem very informative, so I guess it has a predefined (or agreed upon) meaning? What does it mean / what is the purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: `!` is Spec#'s not-null invariant.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178747/what-does-mean-in-c

Comment: @Brandon: Thank you. Don't know why that didn't show up.